# How do I fix this code so that it fetches only updated records?

Tags: ios, web-services

I have an app that uses Ray Wenderlich SDSyncEngine & SDAFParseAPIClient, but Ive modified it to use my client's web service.  When creating the fetch request, it uses a string to append to the GET that specified to only download records after updatedAt date.  I log it here:

```
-[SDAFParseAPIClient GETRequestForAllRecordsOfClass:updatedAfterDate:] [Line 69] jsonString = {"updatedAt":{"$gte":{"__type":"Date","iso":"1900-01-01T00:00:00.999Z"}}}

-[SDAFParseAPIClient GETRequestForClass:parameters:] [Line 54] request <NSMutableURLRequest http://myserver.com/api_address_which_returns_XML_JSON?where=%7B%22updatedAt%22%3A%7B%22%24gte%22%3A%7B%22__type%22%3A%22Date%22%2C%22iso%22%3A%221900-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.999Z%22%7D%7D%7D>
```

That string is produced by this method:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)GETRequestForAllRecordsOfClass:(NSString *)className updatedAfterDate:(NSDate *)updatedDate {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
    NSDictionary *paramters = nil;
    if (updatedDate) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'999Z'"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

        NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                                stringWithFormat:@"{\"updatedAt\":{\"$gte\":{\"__type\":\"Date\",\"iso\":\"%@\"}}}",
                                [dateFormatter stringFromDate:updatedDate]];
        NSLog(@"jsonString = %@", jsonString);
        paramters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonString forKey:@"where"];
    }

    request = [self GETRequestForClass:className parameters:paramters];
    return request;
}
```

Which is originally from the tutorial.  My webservice doesnt use date in iso format inside a dictionary.  So I changed the code to:

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"updatedAt\":%@}",
                                [dateFormatter stringFromDate:updatedDate]];
```

and got this:

```
jsonString = {"updatedAt":1900-01-01T00:00:00.999Z}
```

but for some reason its not working, im still getting all the records from the web service each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the request you are posting on web server may be wrong. Please print the request string and then check it again.
The request you are sending having space that is the reason convert updatedAt : string to utf8encode and then check it again. 
It may will help you.

Comment: This is the request: `request <NSMutableURLRequest http://server.com/webservice/ResponseStores?ClientID=104&KeyString=fd8w788f&where=%7B%22updatedAt%22%3A1900-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.999Z%7D>`

Comment: wher‌​e=%7B%22updatedAt%22%3A1900-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.999Z%7D the & is missing before updatedAt it should be
wher‌​e=%7B%22&updatedAt%22%3A1900-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.999Z%7D

Comment: I inserted a & into the jsonString format line but got this: `request <NSMutableURLRequest http://server.com/webservice/ResponseStores?ClientID=104&KeyString=fd8w788f&where=%7B%22%26updatedAt%22%3A1900-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.999Z%7D>`

Comment: can u tell me what is the jsonString after adding the &.

Comment: i know, it didnt add it.  I just inserted it like this:  `        NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"&updatedAt\"=%@}", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:updatedDate]];
` ---- where request is `request <NSMutableURLRequest http://server.com/webservice/ResponseStores?ClientID=104&KeyString=fd8w788f&where=%7B%22%26updatedAt%22%3D1900-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.999Z%7D>` ---- and jsonString is `jsonString = {"&updatedAt"=1900-01-01T00:00:00.999Z}
`

Comment: if jsonString = {"&updatedAt"=1900-01-01T00:00:00.999Z} then why it is not shown in your request url string please check your code again this is the only issue either in passing the parameter.